# .htaccess file conflict with another rule

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

Redirect /index https://example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://example.com/$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Corporate Gifts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^corporate-gifts/([^/]+)$ gift-category.php?slug=$1 [L]

# Services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ sub-category.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2 [L]

#Uncomment the following lines as you create the pages.
#ErrorDocument 400 /400.php 
#Bad Request 

#ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
#Unautorized

#ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
#Forbidden

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php
#Not Found

#ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
#Internal Server Error

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

On our website there are two types of categories, "services" and the second is corporate gifts. for the service category page, I add the rewrite rule as above the `.htaccess` code. Our service page menu is like that (Service -> Uniform -> School Uniform) dynamic value comes from the admin side. for the second tab menu corporate gifts we create one .php page named `corporate-gifts.php`.

I need corporate gift page menu like that (Corporate Gifts -> Apparel -> Badges). When we click on the page corporate gifts its work fine but when I click on apparel page in subcategory then corporate gifts main category page open rather then sub category. how to apply .htaccess rule for different category in menu bar.

I try above .htaccess code i need a solution for conflict problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by making your rules more specific and ensuring they don't overlap :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Corporate Gifts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^corporate-gifts/([^/]+)$ gift-category.php?slug=$1 [L]

# Services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ sub-category.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

[Test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e5757576-fab1-4b53-9703-d5a86554f99e)

Comment: as you mention for services rule working fine. https://example.com/services/uniform. but for corporate gifts still problem not solved https://example.com/corporate-gifts/apparel. when i try to open apparel page then corporate-gifts page re-open.

Comment: for your information corporate-gifts.php page name we create manually and under their sub category gift-category.php values comes dynamically from admin panel.

Comment: I see.. Let me update my answer

Comment: sure, waiting for your update

Comment: still updated code not work

Comment: i updated my question code for check full version of my .htaccess code might help you more with details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

Redirect /index https://example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://example.com/$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Corporate Gifts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^corporate-gifts/([^/]+)$ gift-category.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]

# Services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^services/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ sub-category.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#Uncomment the following lines as you create the pages.
#ErrorDocument 400 /400.php 
#Bad Request 

#ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
#Unautorized

#ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
#Forbidden

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php
#Not Found

#ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
#Internal Server Error

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I post my answer for correct method. i change the rule position of my code and now its working fine without conflict problem.